# How to measure session time in android?

Tags: android, session, push-notification, analytics

We want to measure session time when the user opens notification sent by us with the unique id.

We want to track how many people opened notification, if opened what is session time and update it in the database for make better decisions about notification in future.

As notification is the powerful way for user engagement. We should send right notification at the right time to the right user.

Is there any way or library to measure session time manually programmatically?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Isn't it enough to send the elapsed time between the showing of the notification  (and you know when it happened because you created it) and the time when the user clicks on it?

Comment: @kingston We are tracking time when we send notification and user open it. Actual question is how we can measure session time (how much time user spend on the application for launch with that notification).

Comment: You already take a timestamp of when the notification was taken, so why don't you also just take one in the next onPause()?

Comment: @cigogne-eveillée I think measuring session time in onPause is not the right way. A user might navigate to multiple activities. the app might go in the background for few seconds if the user is sharing something. Just check fabric document how they measure session time https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-metrics.html